# How to set image height to other part of div with same class names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have these 3 container divs and inside it textdiv is floated left and image div is floated right. I want to set the height of the image as per the height of the text. Is there anyway to do this using jQuery? Or should I give different class names to each div and set the height?

```
<div class='containerr'>
  <div class='textdiv'></div>
  <div class='imagediv'></div>
</div>    
<div class='containerr'>
    <div class='textdiv'></div>
     <div class='imagediv'></div>
</div>     
<div class='containerr'>
    <div class='textdiv'></div>
    <div class='imagediv'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: why would you set the height in jquery and not just css? can you include your code to float right/left?

Comment: because in each text div, text varies and so height of containerr varies but image height does not. I want to render the image all along the div

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that shows your problem and what you are expecting?

Comment: this might help: https://plnkr.co/edit/gM2amcTOWa9Abc91imS2?p=info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this snippet

`$('.containerr').each(function(){

    $this = $(this);
    var textHeight = $this.find(".textdiv");
    var imageHeight = textHeight.height();
    $(".imagediv").css("height", imageHeight);
});`

Answer (score 0):

[CSS3 Flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1) can help with difficult layout challenges that were once difficult or impossible with floats alone:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.textdiv, .imagediv {
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
  <div class="containerr">
<div class="textdiv"><p>Smapmle text.</p></div>
    <div class="imagediv"></div>
</div>
<div class="containerr">
    <div class="textdiv"><p>Smapmle text.</p><p>Smapmle text.</p></div>
    <div class="imagediv"></div>
</div>
<div class="containerr">
    <div class="textdiv"><p>Smapmle text.</p></div>
    <div class="imagediv"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.containerr {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid black; 
  position: relative;
}

.textdiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
}

.imagediv {
  position: absolute;
  display:block;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:red;
}
```